# bootstrap button size as the browser size decreases so that it's eventually xs

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap button like the following:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="/add_post/" style="text-decoration:none">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
    make post
    <span style="float:right">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
    </span>
  </button>
</a>
```

this looks awesome when it's in full screen but as I manipulate with screen size the text "make post" goes out of the box and the shape of box becomes fatter. I want to prevent this but how? 
I thought bootstrap does "mobile first" when it gets down to mobile, it looks ok. but not perfect. I want my whole col-sm-3 to be in bootstrap dropdown button when it's in mobile. How do I do that?

Comment: if you can provide Code it will be better

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try css **white-space** property in button

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom:4px;white-space: normal;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. blah blah blah</a>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nadimsajib/rsez5qk2/)